# Tabbarcontroller behaviour - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, ibaction

[image: flow] 
I'm trying to arrive at tab bar C on IBAction from a button the newViewController. But when I arrive the tab bar controller shows A's view instead of C's view. If using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyInitialViewController"];
[vc presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

I end up creating view of C tab bar with no tabbar options and navigation bar like this 
[image: c]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboards and want to keep the navigation bar and tab bar, you should use

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyInitialViewController" sender:self];
```

instead of using modal presentation